# SQL SERVER Function to given place (Latitude ,Longitude)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have a table which have various entry of place (Latitude, Longitude, Place etc).

I want to write a function which will get a (Latitude, Longitude & a range, say 1 km) and will return the matched Places from that table

Anybody can help me to write this Store procedure or function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FindMatch(@lat1 FLOAT, @lon1 FLOAT,@d INT,@tc INT)    
DECLEAR 
RETURNS FLOAT     
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN  lat=asin(sin(@lat1)*cos(@d)+cos(@lat1)*sin(@d)*cos(@tc))
     IF (cos(lat)=0)
        lon=@lon1      
     ELSE
        lon=mod(@lon1-asin(sin(@tc)*sin(@d)/cos(lat))+pi,2*pi)-pi
     ENDIF
END
```

Comment: I would guess you'd be familiar with the basic a2+b2=c2 pithagor equation, and use it to find distance ?